# Nested loop in StringTemplate

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

Im interested in writting something similar to a nested loop using StringTemplate template engine.
In C# have a HashTable of which each Key contains List of Document objects, each Document has a title and source. I would like to list at the beggining of an email, a summary of the document titles per source.

```
<h1>Summary</h1>
<h2>Source A</h2>
<ul>
  <li>title 1</li>
  <li>title 2</li> 
</ul>
<h2>Source B</h2>
<ul>
  <li>title 3</li>
  <li>title 4</li> 
</ul>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this with StringTemplate?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you've transformed these to appropriate data structures -- `Source` class having `getName` and `getDocuments` methods, and `Document` class having `getTitle` method, it will look like this:

```
$
sources:
 {
    source|
    <h2>Source $source.name$ </h2>
    $
    source.documents:
     {
      document|
      <li>title $document.title$</li>
     }
    $
 }
$
```

Comment: This is a good answer for general objects, but does not work for a HashTable.

Comment: Could you show me a way how your hashtable and document objects look like? With hashtable, you may use `ht.keys:{k|something}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice post that can help you to understand basics of StringTemplate:

[Localizable text template engine using StringTemplate 4](http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/04/localizable-text-template-engine-using_23.html)